# Spring: two beans qualified different with the same name

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Two beans qualidied different with the same name are getting me an exception.

Exception message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'tipusFonsSql', defined in class path resource [net/gencat/clt/arxius/connector/config/SqlGiacTxtResourceLoader.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [net/gencat/clt/arxius/connector/config/SqlGiacImgResourceLoader.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

It's telling me that class `SqlGiacTxtResourceLoader` and class `SqlGiacImgResourceLoader` are defining two beans with a same name.

Nevertheless, they are `"@Qualified"` different. I mean:

Into `SqlGiacImgResourceLoader`

```java
@Bean
@GiacImg @TipusFonsQ
public String tipusFonsSql() {
    //...
}
```

Into `SqlGiacTxtResourceLoader`

```java
@Bean
@GiacTxt @TipusFonsQ
public String tipusFonsSql() {
    //...
}
```

As you can see, one is `"@aulified"` with `@GiacImg` annotation and the other ony by `@GiacTxt`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot have the same id for different beans. So this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to name them like this

```
@Bean(name = "GiacImg TipusFonsQ")
public String tipusFonsSql() {
    //...
}
```

and

```
@Bean(name = "GiacTxt TipusFonsQ")
public String tipusFonsSql() {
    //...
}
```

to avoid bean conflict

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to resolve this issue ( haha there could be many but I know below 2 approach):------

**1st Method**

change the bean name:---

```
@Bean(name = "custome bean name")
```

**2nd Method**

write down the below key in the application.properties:--

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

**NOTE:-in your case you can change method name also**